# currency localization asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I'm trying to implement currency localization like default currency is USD when user change the currency to EUR all product prices in USD will be convert into EUR. I have created a simple resource file for this but don't know what to do next. Please guide me with this i have searched internet but couldn't found any appropriate solution.

Comment: You must give more information. Show some code: how are you showing the prices? where do you get them from? How would you stablish the exchange rate? There are many things, and not clues of what you're doing

Comment: Do you really think that the official conversion rate of the currencies is appropriate? Professional sales people will have different prices for different countries! Often an item priced say 500 Euro in germany will be sold at 500 USD in the US (not 680)...

Comment: @BernhardHiller the data i have is appropriate i just want to simply convert it from USD to any user specified currecny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a base static helper method to set the right currency everywhere on your application once and it will apply across your whole application domain using a session variable.

So you just set a default value of your session variable as USD and point a selected value of a currency drop-down-list to your session variable.

> ```
> Session["currency"] = //set avalue from drop down list here;
> ```

and to calculate the currency you can link an static helper class to your resource and get a selected currency.

```
  public static double CalcCurrency(double price)
  {
       //from your resource
       return GetCurrency(Session["currency"].ToString(), price);  
  }
```

Now in you web pages you everywhere that you have an associate price then you must use the helper method above:

> ```
> asp.net: Price: <%: CalcCurrency(200.55) %>
>   Razor:  Price: @{ CalcCurrency(200.55) }
> ```

Using Session variable is only one option if you don't like to use it you could use ViewBag or ViewData as well. the advantage of Session is you users will get the selected currency across the whole application without you maintaining this yourself for every single view.

Comment: Thanks for this great help, but can u please elaborate it more, like i'm getting currency values from database in USD so how i can set up a helper to convert all those USD values into EUR or any other currency? i have  set up currency conversion method

Comment: If you have not find where to take the currency for free, you can download the xml to convert USD to menny other currency at this url
//http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/USD/rss.xml then use Amount * Rate to get the approximation conversion. i said approximation because the amount is always different when passing to paypal, i guess they charge a % for the conversion. What i do: i download it then keep it in bd, then use from bd if it have downloaded in less an hour. The suply UTC date time of the last update in the xml. Sorry for my bas english, im french.
If you need some code, just ask.